# Devise Custom Session Controller not Persisting Flash Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I decided to customize(override) Devise's session controller to implement my own sign in logic. I've left the sessions#new controller alone and simply call super in it.

```
def new
  super
end
```

However, I have removed the call to super in my custom sessions#create method so that I can send an HTTP request to a server for authentication. Subsequently, I either sign in the user or return the user to the sessions#new path to try their login again.

```
def create
   @member = Member.find_by_username(params[:username])
   response = authenticate_with_api
   if response[:authenticated]
     if @member
       @member.update(response.[:member])
       sign_in @member
     else
       @member.create(response.[:member])
       sign_in @member
     end
   else
     flash[:alert] = "Incorrect username or password"
     flash[:error] = "Incorrect username or password"
     flash[:notice] = "Incorrect username or password" #setting all the messages out of frustration!
     redirect_to new_member_session_path
   end
```

The logic flow is working correctly, however the flash messages are not displaying. I have set a flash message just before calling super in the new method to ensure that the view was setup properly:

```
def new
  flash[:notice] = "Test flash message"
  super
end
```

This works. I can see the flash message appear in the template. The only explanation I can come up with is that somehow, there are multiple redirects occurring. However, when I look in the logs, I can only see the redirect I specified. I have also tried using keep to persist the flash message through multiple requests, but even that does not work:

```
flash.keep[:notice] = "Test flash message"
redirect_to new_member_session_path #does not work
```

I also tried using now as a last ditch effort:

```
flash.now[:notice] = "Test flash message"
```

No dice. Lastly, I have tried placing the flash message inline with the redirect:

```
redirect_to new_member_session_path, flash: { :notice => "Test flash message" } #also does not work
```

I am at a loss. Not sure why the flash messages are being lost. I am running Rails 4.1.2 and Devise 3.2.4

EDIT:

I have decided this is not the best way to customize authentication. Instead, I've created a custom Warden strategy and told devise about it:

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.intercept_401 = false
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :member).unshift :member_login
end
```

I put all my logic in that file:

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:member_login) do
  def member_params
    ActionController::Parameters.new(@response).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :role, :username, :parkplace_user_id)
  end

  def valid?
    params[:member] && ( params[:member][:username] || params[:member][:password] )
  end

  def authenticate!
    member = Member.find_by_username(params[:member][:username])
    if authenticate_with_ppd_api
      if member
        member.update(member_params)
        success!(member)
      else
        member = Member.create(member_params)
        success!(member)
      end
    else
      fail!("Incorrect username or password")
    end
  end

  def authenticate_with_api
    @response = HTTParty.post('https://path.to.server/admin/login', body: { username: params[:member][:username], password: params[:member][:password] } )
    @response = JSON.parse(@response.body).first
    @response["authenticated"]
  end

end
```

Flash messages are appearing now, but I have other problems with sign in. I created a new question for that. Thanks!

Comment: Since no one answered yet I'll suggest trying a 'flash.now[:type]'?

Comment: Yep, I tried that, too! I will update my question. Thanks!

Comment: what action does `new_member_session_path` refer to? does *that* action have a redirect in it?

Comment: The controller#action is members/sessions#new

Comment: There is a respond_with, but not another redirect

Comment: Did you ever solve it?